# Trying to read CSV file in Python but encountering strange characters

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to open and read a csv file using the python csv module. My codes is as follows.

```
import csv

with open('sample2.csv', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    sample2_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimeter=',')
    for row in sample2_csv:
        print(row)
```

It worked fine for the first couple of lines before it errored. Here's what the program said about why it couldn't read the csv file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(row)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 246: character maps to <undefined>
```

I opened the csv file and it looked normal until I found some strange characters. Here is a snippet of some of the lines that had these strange characters.

```
Often,potenti,1JyVmzshRbmGk6QWmqPcxD7jdFsmuXeC7n,���
Seldom,lacus,1Jmsi539h54f5Bw8ByWjhsRkPHXknXhFLt,��ԋ�_�Ġ�⣋�_�����΋�܋����㋁�
Weekly,quam,1GsDkNCzcN3MxoxvRAUpaEioDeWcgJRV2z,�ۻ�ۻtest�ۻ
```

I'm trying to find which lines meet a specific criteria, sort them, then print them out. How can I deal with these strange characters if I can't even read the whole file right now?

Comment: Have you verified that the encoding of the file is actually utf-8? It seems to be something else. If you are using Linux or the git bash under windows you can use the `file {filename}` command to more or less reliably determine the encoding.

Comment: It could be that your terminal settings or editor do not support unicode.  `cmd.exe` is not very good at displaying non-american characters.  As a test, try it in IDLE.